# How to change a main image when you mouse over a smaller image underneath using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, I am having trouble setting this up. I am trying to call a function when I mouseover a small image, there are five small images, and then use that function to change the big image, but I dont think im doing it right. Should I be doing something differently?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeBigPic1() {
            document.getElementById(bigPic).src = "http://www.worldatlas.com/webimage/flags/usa/usalarge.gif";
        }
        function changeBigPic2() {
            document.getElementById(bigPic).src = "https://pelesagratcor.wikispaces.com/file/view/union_jack.JPG/155615705/400x200/union_jack.JPG";
        }
        function changeBigPic3() {
            document.getElementById(bigPic).src = "http://www.gettysburgflag.com/images/mexico.jpg";
        }
        function changeBigPic4() {
            document.getElementById(bigPic).src = "http://www.printableworldflags.com/large-flags/South%20Africa_National%20Flag_Flag-668.gif";
        }
        function changeBigPic5() {
            document.getElementById(bigPic).src = "http://www.worldatlas.com/webimage/flags/countrys/zzzflags/cnlarge.gif";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Large Image</h1>
    <div>
        <img id="bigPic" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cd/Black_flag.svg/750px-Black_flag.svg.png" width="450" height="280" /> 
    </div>
    <h2>Small Images</h2>
    <div>
        <img id="smallPicUSA" onmouseover="changeBigPic1() "src="http://www.worldatlas.com/webimage/flags/usa/usalarge.gif" width="320" height="200" />
        <img id="smallPicUK"  onmouseover="changeBigPic2() "src="https://pelesagratcor.wikispaces.com/file/view/union_jack.JPG/155615705/400x200/union_jack.JPG" width="320" height="200" />
        <img id="smallPicMEX" onmouseover="changeBigPic3()" src="http://www.gettysburgflag.com/images/mexico.jpg" width="320" height="200" />
        <img id="smallPicSA" onmouseover="changeBigPic4()" src="http://www.printableworldflags.com/large-flags/South%20Africa_National%20Flag_Flag-668.gif" width="320" height="200" />
        <img id="smallPicCHINA" onmouseover="changeBigPic5()" src="http://www.worldatlas.com/webimage/flags/countrys/zzzflags/cnlarge.gif" width="320" height="200" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, is it not working? Are you getting errors? In your functions, what's `bigPic` refer to? Did you mean `'bigPic'`?

Comment: bigPic should be a string 'bigPic'

Comment: Fals has your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a variable to your function with `bigPic` when you really wanted to pass a string, `'bigPic'`.

That aside, you could streamline your code to just the following if you pass the function a parameter of `this.src`:

```
function changeBigPic(flag) {
    document.getElementById('bigPic').src = flag;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wk9we9b6/1/)**

Comment: You're the man! I took your suggestion to clean up my code as well. It works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have your `id` in quotes for your functions.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeBigPic1() {
            document.getElementById("bigPic").src = "http://www.worldatlas.com/webimage/flags/usa/usalarge.gif";
        }
        function changeBigPic2() {
            document.getElementById("bigPic").src = "https://pelesagratcor.wikispaces.com/file/view/union_jack.JPG/155615705/400x200/union_jack.JPG";
        }
        function changeBigPic3() {
            document.getElementById("bigPic").src = "http://www.gettysburgflag.com/images/mexico.jpg";
        }
        function changeBigPic4() {
            document.getElementById("bigPic").src = "http://www.printableworldflags.com/large-flags/South%20Africa_National%20Flag_Flag-668.gif";
        }
        function changeBigPic5() {
            document.getElementById("bigPic").src = "http://www.worldatlas.com/webimage/flags/countrys/zzzflags/cnlarge.gif";
        }
    </script>
```

Right now, your functions are looking for a variable named `bigPic` when you mouseover. If you put it in quotes, then it will look for that `id`.

Answer (score 0):

- I found some possible errors.You defined image size and width in your html image tag which means whatever the src of large image change, your images width and height will not be change.
- you have to use ("bigPic") instead of (bigPic)